# Не работает пагинация на WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Вот код

```
                 $postArr = [];
                    if(have_posts()) : query_posts("showposts=5&cat=3,4");
                        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            $link = get_permalink();
                            $title = get_the_title();
                            $postContentId = get_the_ID();
                            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                $image = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'miniatures', array('class' => 'alignleft'));
                            } else {
                                $imagePath = get_bloginfo("template_url") . "/img/no_image.jpg";
                                $image = '<img src='.$imagePath.' alt="'.$title.'"/>';
                            }
                            $thumbDesc = get_the_excerpt();
                            $postItem = '<a href='.$link.' data-postid='.$postContentId.' rel="bookmark" class="thumb_3"><div class="img-box">'.$image.'</div><h4>'.$title.'</h4><p>'.$thumbDesc.'</p></a>';
                            array_push($postArr, $postItem);
                        endwhile;
                    if (!empty($postArr)) {
                            echo "<div class='thumbnails_3 thumbnails_3_2 offset_ziro'>".implode('', $postArr)."</div>";
                            the_posts_pagination();
                        } else {
                            echo "Пока у нас нет публикаций";
                        }
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
```

Подскажите почему не работает пагинация?

Comment: Теги лишние уберите, js тут не причем.

Comment: Теги не влияют жеж на пагинацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$postArr = [];
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
if(have_posts()) : query_posts("showposts=5&cat=3,4&paged=".$paged);
```